# Difference between NVIDIA P100 GPUs and Committed NVIDIA P100 GPUs limit name in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gpu, google-kubernetes-engine

Currently, I am trying to increase my quota limit for NVIDIA P100 GPU in GKE. When I filter in Quotas using the **Limit name**, I get two types of options - **NVIDIA P100 GPUs** and **Committed NVIDIA P100 GPUs**. What is the difference between these two?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus#reserving_gpus_with_committed_use_discounts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As their names mean:

- NVIDIA P100 GPUs: quota of GPU that you can use in your project (and attach to a GCE). You pay only when the GPU is attached to an active GCE.
- Committed NVIDIA P100 GPUs: quota of GPU that you can commit (reserve) in your project. You will pay this GPU even if not use or attach to a VM, but you will have a discount